# Python Processing: How to call multiple of the same class

Tags: python, processing

I am a noob at Python and I am having trouble with this problem. I am trying to create a raindrop scene with the 'drop' class. Right now, the code only calls one drop at a time. How can I call multiple drops at once?

Here is my code:

```
import random
class drop():
    def __init__(self):
        # where the drop starts
        self.x = random.randint(20,480)
        self.y = 0
        #how fast the drop falls
        self.yspeed = 5

    def fall(self):
        self.y = self.y+self.yspeed

    def show(self):
        # color of drop
        stroke(1,1,1)
        fill(1,1,1)
        strokeWeight(1)
        line(self.x,self.y,self.x,self.y+10)




def setup():
    size(500,500)
    global d
    d = drop()


def draw():
    background(255,255,255)
    d.fall()
    d.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many instances of a class as you want. For example the following code creates two drops.

```
d1 = drop()
d2 = drop()
```

You can also create a list of drops like this -

```
drops = []
drops.append(drop())
drops.append(drop())
drops[0].fall()
drops[1].show()
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me figure out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty with Python, But I would suggest changing draw to accept an array of elements.

So for example, in setup and can generate an array of droplets by doing:

```py
def setup():
  size(500,500) #Idk what this does, I assume its another function somewhere else in your code
  droplets = [] #The array of droplets we want to render
  for x in range(6): #6 is the number of droplets we want. 
    droplets.append(drop())

#Pass droplets into draw.
def draw(entities):
  background(255,255,255) #Again, IDK what this does but its in your code. I assume it is another function somewhere. 
  for droplet in entities: #Goes through ALL the droplets in the list you passed. 
    droplet.fall() #Calls these methods on every droplet in the array. 
    droplet.show()
```

This is untested, but from here you would somehow pass the droplets array into draw and BOOM you have a bunch of droplets being rendered every draw cycle. I would suggest NOT using global variables. Its just bad practice. You should have another function somewhere that runs all of this, I assume on a time for the draw cycle.